# Unable to load a pcd file using a get request from node server inside inside javascript code using threejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, three.js, point-clouds

I am trying to load a sample pcd file from my server to load it in scene inside 3d canvas in threejs . I have a get request which reads the pcd file and sends it.

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const router = new express.Router()

router.get('/api/pcd', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    try {
      let _path = 'simple.pcd'
      if (fs.existsSync(_path)) {
        fs.readFile(_path, 'utf8', (err, data) => {

          res.send(data)
        })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error')
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e)
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

Inside the javascript code using pcd loader tried to load the point cloud inside the scene.

```
var loader = new THREE.PCDLoader()
      // load a resource
      loader.load(
        'http://localhost:8081/api/pcd',
        function(mesh) {
          scene.add(mesh)
          var center = mesh.geometry.boundingSphere.center
          console.log(center)

          controls.target.set(center.x, center.y, center.z)
          controls.update()
        },
        function(xhr) {
          console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
        },
        function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
```

But this is the error which is coming up. please help.

```
TypeError: geometry.setAttribute is not a function

 at THREE.PCDLoader.parse (PCDLoader.js:361)

 at Object.onLoad (PCDLoader.js:32)

 at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.js:34275)
```

This the code used as reference
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_pcd.html

This is the pcd file
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/models/pcd/ascii/simple.pcd